# Sagemaker Processing doesn't upload

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use the sagemaker processor to replace some processes we run on Amazon batch.

```
from sagemaker.processor import ScriptProcessor 
proc = ScriptProcessor(
    image_uri='your-image-uri', 
    command=['python3'], 
    role=role, 
    instance_count=1, 
    instance_type='m4.4x.large',  
    volume_size_in_gb=500,
    base_job_name='preprocessing-test',
)
proc.run(
    code='test.py',
)
```

First of all, is it true that the `ScriptProcessing` syntax is more complicated than the `TrainingJob` version where you can specify the `source_dir` and `entrypoint` to upload your code to a default container?

Secondly, this code above gives me this error

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "sagemaker-eu-west-1-<account-id>\preprocessing-test-<timestamp>\input\code": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

I guess this key is created internally when trying to upload my `test.py`, but why does it not work? :) The documentation says you can use both local and s3 paths.

Comment: did you find how we can specify source_dir?

Comment: @karan: you can't, and must upload the code in the docker. A bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bucket name `sagemaker-eu-west-1-\preprocessing-test-\input\code looks like a hardcoded string. In SageMaker Python SDK, the code upload function is [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/3bf569ece9e46a097d1ab69286ee89f762931e6c/src/sagemaker/processing.py#L463):

Are you using a Windows environment? As Lauren noted in the comments, there have been some bug fixes there, so make sure to use the last version

Comment: Looks like the line of code that's linked here was fixed recently so as to not use backlashes on Windows - upgrading to [sagemaker==1.55.2](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/releases/tag/v1.55.2) should solve the issue